# Sacar cursor de cuadro de texto

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de sacar el cursor de un cuadro de texto utilizando `tkinter` y que el programa lo vuelva a tomar como antes de pinchar en el cuadro de texto. Esto es para poder seguir utilizando los comandos rápidos del teclado, de la barra de herramientas `NavigationToolbar2Tk` y también insertar textos en la gráfica mediante el cuadro de texto. Gracias.

Pongo una parte del código para poder ver mejor a que me refiero:

```
root = tkinter.Tk ()
frame1=Frame(root)
frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
fig , ax =plt.subplots (dpi=80, sharey=True, figsize=(13,4) )
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame1)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, frame1)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack (side = tkinter.BOTTOM, 
fill=tkinter.BOTH, 
expand=tkinter.YES)
b2 = tkinter.Button(frame1, text="marcar")
b2.pack(side=LEFT)
textExample6=tkinter.Text(frame1,width=47, height=2)
textExample6.pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

La idea es representar una gráfica y mediante el botón "marcar" represento en la gráfica el texto del cuadro de texto, pero al pinchar en el cuadro de texto ya no puedo volver a usar los atajos del teclado para la barra de herramientas:

-Inicio (h)
-Adelante (Flecha derecha)
-Atrás (Flecha izquierda)

Ya que una vez que pincho en el cuadro de texto cualquier acción del teclado me la representa en él.

Comment: Hola @Antonio, se necesita algo más de información para que los usuarios puedan ayudarte. Podrías publicar el código que tienes de momento y que es lo que deseas hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En general lo que he entendido es que usted está intentando retirar el foco del cuadro de texto y también regresarlo, por lo cual, usted no puede retirar el cursor explícitamente en un cuadro de texto, puede es retirar el foco de ese control o regresarlo, eso es lo que he entendido y pues la manera como funciona es agregar una función que retira el foco del cuadro de texto y que devuelva el foco de la ventana o clase inicial de instancia.

**La solución con base en su código usando un programación orientada a objetos:**

```
import tkinter as tk

class WindowExample(tk.Tk): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Agregar los widgets....

        self.b2 = tk.Button(self, text="Enfocar control", command=self.FocusEnCuadroTextoEvento)
        self.b2.pack(side='left')

        self.textExample6=tk.Text(self, width=47, height=2)
        self.textExample6.pack(side='left')

        self.b3 = tk.Button(self, text="Retirar el foco", command=self.NoFocusEnCuadroTextoEvento)
        self.b3.pack(side='left')

    def FocusEnCuadroTextoEvento(self, event=None): # Enfocar el cuadro de texto
        self.textExample6.focus_set()

    def NoFocusEnCuadroTextoEvento(self, event=None): # Retornar el foco a la ventana
        self.focus_set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = WindowExample()
    root.title('Ejemplo ventana')
    root.geometry('600x80')
    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.mainloop() # Fin ciclo de eventos
```

**Usando programación procedimental:**

```
import tkinter as tk


root=tk.Tk()
root.title('Ejemplo ventana')
root.geometry('600x80')
root.resizable(0,0)

def FocusEnCuadroTextoEvento(event=None): # Enfocar el cuadro de texto
    textExample6.focus_set()

def NoFocusEnCuadroTextoEvento(event=None): # Retornar el foco a la ventana
    root.focus_set()

b2 = tk.Button(root, text="Enfocar control", command=FocusEnCuadroTextoEvento)
b2.pack(side='left')

textExample6=tk.Text(root, width=47, height=2)
textExample6.pack(side='left')

b3 = tk.Button(root, text="Retirar el foco", command=NoFocusEnCuadroTextoEvento)
b3.pack(side='left')

root.mainloop() # Fin ciclo de eventos
```

> Nótese que use como controles botones, uno asigna el foco mediante la función `FocusEnCuadroTextoEvento()` al control de texto y el otro solo devuelve el foco a la ventana mediante la función `NoFocusEnCuadroTextoEvento()` usando en ambos `focus_set()`. Estas son las soluciones más viables con respecto a su pregunta *Sacar cursor de cuadro de texto*.